# SPS2013 Open document library PDF's in Modal dialog?

Tags: document, pdf, popup

Can anyone tell me the correct methodology to getting modal popups to work with PDF files in a document library on SharePoint 2013?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When creating the modal dialog, in the options just try setting the URL to the location to the PDF file. I haven't tried this myself with a PDF file but it should work:

```
var options = {
    title: "Modal title",
    url: "/site/documentlibrary/document.pdf",
};

SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
```

Comment: Your solution only appears to be for one file, the document library contains hundreds of PDF files.

Comment: Please be clearer in your question. What is it you are trying to achieve exactly? What's the use case? When a user clicks a PDF in a document library a modal should pop up displaying that PDF?

Comment: Yes thats correct and this should apple to all PDFs.